# I am not really sure what this code does (bit manipulation)

Tags: c, bit-manipulation, bit-shift

I wrote some code I am unit testing right now and for that I made the code below with the help of the internet.

```
//shows changed bit
    //0010 0101 XOR 0010 0111 = 0000 0010 
    uint8_t XOR = value ^ result;

    int count;
    //count amount of 1's in XOR
    for (count = 0; XOR; XOR >>= 1)
    {
        count += XOR & 1;
    }
```

Value is the original value, and result is the value but with ONE bit toggled.

I just want to make sure I understand this correctly but please correct me if I am wrong.

The 2nd statement in the for loop the "XOR;" what I think it does is run the for loop while XOR is not 0. And the XOR >>= 1 is that it sets to its self but with the 1 shifted one place to the right.

And the count does a +1 whenever there is a 1 on the last position ?

That's what I make out of it.

Comment: You're correct. It's counting the number of `1` bits in XOR.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you do

```
  r = a xor b
```

and `a` has only one bit toggled compared to `b`, `r` will have that bit at `1`, always, all the other bits at `0`.

So `count` will always give `1`.

The `for` loop adds one to `count` when the LSb (bit 0, right side) is `1`. Then `XOR` is shifted right, all bits going from left to right, the bit 0 taking the value of bit 1 etc. The MSb (bit 7) takes value `0` (`XOR` is unsigned, so no problem if the MSb was `1` initially).

Thus, eventually `XOR` will be `0` and the loop will stop.